# mapbox set clickable to false in geoJSON

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

With MapBox, how do you set "clickable" to false with GeoJSON as in the following.  I’ve tried adding clickable to the properties object, but no luck.  I’ve also tried adding it in the layeradd event but it likely does not update back to the DOM:

```
    function setCustomIcon() {

        var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(moMap);

        var geoJson = [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-113.5, 53.5]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Current Location",
                "icon": {
                    "iconUrl": "current-location.png",
                    "iconSize": [32, 32], // size of the icon
                    "iconAnchor": [16, 16] // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                }
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-113, 53.5]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Vehicle",
                "icon": {
                    "iconUrl": "Images/VehicleRing.svg",
                    "iconSize": [23, 23],
                    "iconAnchor": [12, 12]
                }
            }
        }];

        // Set a custom icon on each marker based on feature properties.
        myLayer.on('layeradd', function (e) {
            var marker = e.layer,  // this is a marker - Leaflet calls it a layer...
                feature = marker.feature;

            marker.setIcon(L.icon(feature.properties.icon));
        });

        // Add features to the map.
        myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things to do, the first is setting the marker options to `clickable` is false, the second is overruling the cursor style so it doesn't look like there is something to click.

The first you can accomplish by not letting `L.mapbox.featureLayer` automaticly turn your point features into markers. You can do that by using the `pointToLayer` method in the options of `L.mapbox.featureLayer`. That method will get called for every point feature in your GeoJSON collection and will let you return your own layertype. In your case an `L.Marker` with the `clickable` option set to false:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
        return new L.Marker(latLng, {
            clickable: false
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Next the second thing, overruling the cursor style set to `.leaflet-marker-icon`. It's set to `pointer` so it looks like there is something to click, you'll need to set it to grab, just like the one that's used on the mapcontainer:

```
.leaflet-marker-icon {
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab
}
```

That's it. Here's an example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5GvS81?p=preview

PS. In your case it would be good to be already using the `pointToLayer` function. It prevents you from afterwards having to loop over the features in the layer to set the `L.Icon`:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
        return new L.Marker(latLng, {
            icon: new L.Icon(feature.properties.icon)
        });
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: iH8, thank you very much for this detailed solution.  It is exactly what I need.